# ag-Grid - show buttons on row hover like in Gmail - Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there a way to achieve it in Angular. I tried the solution given in this answer,

[ag-Grid - show buttons on row hover like in Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364899/ag-grid-show-buttons-on-row-hover-like-in-gmail)

If there's a way to make it work in Angular, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work as straight forward in Angular is due to the styling. You need to apply the style to the child component of the element, i.e. `ag-grid-angular`. To do this, you need to use the css selector `::ng-deep` to apply the styling, although this is not recommended as this will soon be deprecated.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-jq4xdt?file=src/app/app.component.html).